# Buttons changing images

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 buttons and 3 images. When one button is pressed the other 2 images fade to opacity: 0 , but for some reason the javascript code is doing nothing. One button is supposed to change bootstrap color and fade out the other images while the current image fades in. Can anyone tell me why?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="allMenus">
        <div id="menuButtons">
            <div id="breakfastButton">
                <button class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-toggle="button" id=
                "breakfastButtonActive" type="button">Breakfast</button>
            </div>

            <div id="lunchButton">
                <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="button"
                id="lunchMenuActive" type="button">Lunch</button>
            </div>

            <div id="specialsButton">
                <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="button"
                id="specialsMenuActive" type="button">Weekly Specials</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="menuBreakfast"><img alt="" src=
    "SleepingMoonImages/menuBreakfast.png" width="342"></div>

    <div id="menuLunch"><img alt="" height="840" src=
    "SleepingMoonImages/menuLunch.png" width="342"></div>

    <div id="menuSpecials">
        <img alt="" src="SleepingMoonImages/menuSpecials.png" width="342">

        <div id="weeklySpecialsLabel">
            Weekly Specials
        </div>

        <div id="redUnderline"></div>

        <div id="weeklySpecialsDays">
            <div id="mondayLabel">
                Monday
            </div>

            <div id="tuesdayLabel">
                Tuesday
            </div>

            <div id="wednesdayLabel">
                Wednesday
            </div>

            <div id="thursdayLabel">
                Thursday
            </div>

            <div id="fridayLabel">
                Friday
            </div>

            <div id="saturdayLabel">
                Saturday
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript File

```
$(document).ready(function () {



$("#breakfastButton").click(function (e) {
    $('#menuLunch').fadeTo(200, 0);
    $('#menuBreakfast').fadeTo(200, 2);
    $('#menuSpecials').fadeTo(200, 0);

    $("#breakfastButtonActive").removeClass('btn btn-large btn-primary').addClass('btn btn-large btn-info');
    $("#lunchMenuActive").removeClass('btn btn-large btn-info').addClass('btn btn-large btn-primary');
    $("#specialsMenuActive").removeClass('btn btn-large btn-info').addClass('btn btn-large btn-primary');
});

$("#lunchButton").click(function (e) {
    $('#menuBreakfast').fadeTo(200, 0);
    $('#menuLunch').fadeTo(200, 2);
    $('#menuSpecials').fadeTo(200, 0);
    $("#lunchMenuActive").removeClass(' btn-primary').addClass('btn-info');
    $("#breakfastButtonActive").removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-primary');
    $("#specialsMenuActive").removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-primary');
});

$("#specialsButton").click(function (e) {
    $('#menuBreakfast').fadeTo(200, 0);
    $('#menuLunch').fadeTo(200, 0);
    $('#menuSpecials').fadeTo(200, 2);
    $("#lunchMenuActive").removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-primary');
    $("#breakfastButtonActive").removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-primary');
    $("#specialsMenuActive").removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-info');

});
```

});

Comment: for one thing: why do you add and  remove the same classes in the same line of code? just remove or add the one you want.

Comment: If I don't remove the btn-info and then add btn-primary then the colors of the buttons don't change how I want them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the ids for `menuBreakfast` and `menuLunch` in the script doesn't match the ids in your HTML where you use `breakfastMenu` and `lunchMenu`. Adjusted [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/VRit8Kxxms) with some cleanup to add and remove only the classes that are different instead of adding and removing also the classes that should just stay the same and a second [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/HtJyuVURfy) with the addition of setting `#menuLunch` and `#menuSpecials` to `display:none` as initially `#menuBreakfast` is active (so only the breakfast dummy image is displayed).

As mentioned in comments, Bootstrap was down for some minutes, so in addition as stack snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#breakfastButton").click(function (e) {
        $('#menuLunch').fadeTo(200, 0);
        $('#menuBreakfast').fadeTo(200, 2);
        $('#menuSpecials').fadeTo(200, 0);

        $("#breakfastButtonActive").removeClass('btn btn-large btn-primary').addClass('btn btn-large btn-info');
        $("#lunchMenuActive").removeClass('btn btn-large btn-info').addClass('btn btn-large btn-primary');
        $("#specialsMenuActive").removeClass('btn btn-large btn-info').addClass('btn btn-large btn-primary');
    });

    $("#lunchButton").click(function (e) {
        $('#menuBreakfast').fadeTo(200, 0);
        $('#menuLunch').fadeTo(200, 2);
        $('#menuSpecials').fadeTo(200, 0);
        $("#lunchMenuActive").removeClass(' btn-primary').addClass('btn-info');
        $("#breakfastButtonActive").removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-primary');
        $("#specialsMenuActive").removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-primary');
    });

    $("#specialsButton").click(function (e) {
        $('#menuBreakfast').fadeTo(200, 0);
        $('#menuLunch').fadeTo(200, 0);
        $('#menuSpecials').fadeTo(200, 2);
        $("#lunchMenuActive").removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-primary');
        $("#breakfastButtonActive").removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-primary');
        $("#specialsMenuActive").removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-info');
    });
});
```

```css
#menuLunch , #menuSpecials
{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="allMenus">
    <div id="menuButtons">
        <div id="breakfastButton">
            <button id="breakfastButtonActive" class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-toggle="button" type="button">Breakfast</button>
        </div>
        <div id="lunchButton">
            <button id="lunchMenuActive" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="button" type="button">Lunch</button>
        </div>
        <div id="specialsButton">
            <button id="specialsMenuActive" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="button" type="button">Weekly Specials</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="menuBreakfast">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/342x50/cccccc/000000.jpg&text=Breakfast" width="342" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="menuLunch">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/342x50/cccccc/000000.jpg&text=Lunch" width="342" height="50" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="menuSpecials">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/342x50/cccccc/000000.jpg&text=Specials" width="342" alt="" />
    <div id="weeklySpecialsLabel">Weekly Specials</div>
    <div id="redUnderline"></div>
    <div id="weeklySpecialsDays">
        <div id="mondayLabel">Monday</div>
        <div id="tuesdayLabel">Tuesday</div>
        <div id="wednesdayLabel">Wednesday</div>
        <div id="thursdayLabel">Thursday</div>
        <div id="fridayLabel">Friday</div>
        <div id="saturdayLabel">Saturday</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The Bootply doesn't work. Also I updated my code based on what you said and it still isn't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user6680  Bootply worked but the app is down as the error message says. It's also in this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w4zx483p/  without the bootstrap styles.

Comment: I can see it's working in jsfiddle and I used the suggested changes, but the issue still persists. Maybe you can tell me what's causing the problem from a live demo. http://www.andrewhnovak.com/SleepingMoonCafe/SleepingMoonCafeSite/index.html

Comment: I even wrote document.write('hello'); in the lunchButton click function and nothing happened. So I don't think it's seeing the menu.js file I'm using but it is imported in the <head> So I don't know why nothing is happening unless something is interfering with the imported js file

Comment: @user6680 This could be the reason why it's not working - you have to load your script - `js/menu.js` - in the body _after_ jquery.

Comment: I didn't realize that I couldn't insert the script in the head, but that fixed my problem. Thanks matthias_h!

Comment: @user6680 Glad I was able to help and that it's now working for you. If this answered your question, you can consider to accept this answer so the question will be marked as closed / solved. Just in case you don't know how this works and why, check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235